# Using HTTPS with URIs on Mediawiki

Tags: https, nginx, uri, mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki install running on a Ubuntu 12.04 server using Nginx as the webserver. I have also created a self signed certificate to use with the site so that when I log in, my passwords would not be exposed to everyone on the internet.

Recently, I noticed the the site does not properly load the CSS for the site. Upon closer inspection it appears that my browser (firefox) is blocking certain content because it is apparently insecure. It seems to not like that the images on the site are being referenced by uri instead of using https:// but I am not sure how to correct this. Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Could you provide a URL where you are seeing this?

Comment: I might be wrong, but this issue should only affect you if you somehow chose to tell the browser not to show the insecure objects, the thing is you have some assets provided through `http` while the page as a whole is `https` so the browser considers them insecure, to solve it make sure that all the assets in your page are served using `https`

Comment: @MarkA.Hershberger https://wiki.asedmunds.ca/

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I have not explictly told the browser to block these settings. It appears to be the default for Chrome and Firefox to block insecure content on mixed security pages.

Comment: Yea I just tested the link you provided, Firefox showed a popup when i clicked the shield icon that's next to the address bar, It seems that it became the default behavior at some point, What's the problem with changing all these links to https ?

Comment: I just tried the asset link, it did redirect to https, but apparently the browser blocks it before noticing the redirection header, so it's better to solve it from the app it self

Comment: That's the part I need help with. I can't seem to find any information oh how to make media wiki totally compatible with SSL and have it running as a secure site.

I did find this link, http://pario.no/2009/01/30/enable-secure-ssl-login-on-mediawiki/ which helps point me in the correct direction but the PHP script he has listed appears to only use SSL for the sign in page whereas I want to use SSL for the whole site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try using [protocol-relative URIs](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) for $wgServer in your LocalSettings.php.  For example, it looks like you have:

```
$wgServer = "http://wiki.asedmunds.ca";
```

Try

```
$wgServer = "//wiki.asedmunds.ca";
```

instead.